# Exporting only select feature properties to CSV file from Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to calculate the number of fires for a region and export the result to Google Drive as a CSV file. The code I'm using to do this seems to work, but the object `fire_ind_count` contains many additional properties besides fire count.

How can I alter my code to obtain an object with only the count of fires to export?

```
// Load country shapefile 
var lsib = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");
var vn_shape = lsib.filterMetadata('country_na', 'equals', 'Argentina');
print (vn_shape);

// Load fire counts image
var fire = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS')
             .filterBounds(vn_shape)
             .filterDate('2019', '2020');
var scale = fire.first().projection().nominalScale();

// Filter fire with more than 50% confidence and add a new band representing areas where confidence of fire > 50%
var filterConfidence = function(image) {
  var line_number = image.select('line_number');
  var confidence = image.select('confidence');
  var conf_50 = confidence.gt(50).rename('confidence_50');
  var count_band = line_number.updateMask(conf_50).rename('count');
  return image.addBands(count_band);
};
var fire_conf = fire.map(filterConfidence);
print('fire_conf', fire_conf);

// Count for individual image.
var countIndividualImg = function(image) {
  var countObject = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.countDistinct(),
    scale: scale,
    geometry: vn_shape,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  return image.set(countObject);
};
var fire_ind_count = fire_conf.map(countIndividualImg);
print('fire_ind_count', fire_ind_count);
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: fire_ind_count,
  description: 'FireCountsInAustralia_gt50_conf'});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, all properties of a collection will be exported. You can use the `selectors` argument to specify the properties you want to export.

```
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: fire_ind_count,
  description: 'FireCountsInAustralia_gt50_conf',
  selectors:['count']
});
```