# Exporting table without .geo and system:index in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How do I export a table (CSV) without *.geo* and *system:index* in Google Earth Engine?

These two parameters are automatically added when I make a feature.

What I'm trying to do is extract some properties from Image Collection and export CSV of them.

```
var featColl = someImgCollection.map(function (image) {
    var someValA = image.get("someValueA");
    var someValB = image.get("someValueB");
    var object = {
        someValueA: someValA,
        someValueB: someValB
    }
    var feature = ee.Feature(null, object);  
    return feature;
});

Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: featureCollection,
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Then I'd like to remove "system:index" and ".geo" from the result.

| system:index | someValueA | someValueB | .geo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020_01_01 | 20 | 34 |  |
| 2020_01_02 | 14 | 21 |  |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply provide an array of the properties/columns you want exported in the `selectors` property.

```
var collection = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([0, 0]), {
    foo: 'A',
    bar: 'B'
  })
])

Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: collection,
    selectors: ['foo', 'bar']
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b1a512469bb452a2f5a5e84c2bf52a39

Comment: Thank you! It's a useful option. I'm ashamed of myself spending some time without checking docs well and also sorry for the duplicated questions, I just found. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348606/export-only-select-feature-properties-to-a-csv-file-from-earth-engine

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using *.select()* for when you are dealing with a lot of properties. If you just want to select all except exporting the .geo values to the csv, you can try this one:

```
var collection = ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-54.11113281250001, 37.461515212585624],
      [-54.46269531250001, 36.760625534542804],
      [-54.37480468750001, 35.41116773646161],
      [-49.80449218750001, 35.482768058471024],
      [-50.59550781250001, 38.91214931918128],
      [-54.46269531250001, 38.224974683387785]]]),  {
foo: 'A',
bar: 'B',
foo2: 'A',
bar2: 'B',
foo3: 'A',
bar3: 'B'  })]);

Export.table.toDrive({
collection: collection.select(['.*'],null,false)});
```

Please find the test link here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/b89b4a3bf5dd258e61e7e99d5fd43d79